# include shell command into program python

Tags: python

Community

I'm currently trying to implement a program that includes the following shell command:

```
/home/myfolder/ParZu/parzu -l tagged < /home/myfolder/raw_text_de/raw_text_de0.txt >/home/myfolder/raw_text_de0_parsed.txt
```

`/home/myfolder/ParZu/parzu` is the program I want to run, `-l` and `tagged` are options to go with the program and I want to feed in my `raw_text_de0.txt` and write the result into another file `raw_text_de0_parsed.txt`.

The thing is, that I have to do this more than 400 times (for file `raw_text_de1.txt`, `raw_text_de2.txt`....), which is why I really want to automatize it.

I tried several things that have been suggested here on Stackoverflow, but none seems to work. My current attempt looks as follows:

```
path_texts = '/home/myfolder/raw_text_de'
filename = os.listdir(path_texts)

##create list of filenames ('/home/myfolder/raw_text_de/raw_text_de0.txt', ...)
infile_list = []
for fname in filename: 
    new_filename = '/home/myfolder/raw_text_de/' + fname
    infile_list.append(new_filename)

##go through the files in the infile_list and include it in shell command
for item in infile_list: 
    p = subprocess.call(['/home/myfolder/ParZu/parzu', '-l', 'tagged', '<', item, '>', item + 'parsed.txt'])
```

However, this doesn't work. It apparently calls the program, but then gets stuck. I know that it is difficult to answer this question without being able to try it, but I hope someone has an idea about what could be wrong or missing.

Comment: wouldn't os.commandline() work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` has two arguments: `stdin` and `stdout`. Take advantage of them instead of putting the redirection operators `>` and `<` in the arguments.

In your case:

```
for item in infile_list: 
    infile = file(item)
    outfile = file(item + 'parsed.txt','w')
    p = subprocess.call(['/home/myfolder/ParZu/parzu', '-l', 'tagged'], stdin=infile, stdout=outfile)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It would have been better if you could print some of your outputs of that call here.

However, I guess the problem is in your parameters of that call.

Here is the proper argument list of **subprocess.call()**

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

And you can check the return result of your call individually just to make sure it's working fine.

```
subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"])

subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
```

Details could be found here:

[subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)